# Limiting nested class methods access to it's container class (C#)

Tags: c#, inner-classes

So I'm trying to create a nested class that handles all sort of global methods and is accessible by other classes.

To do so I nested the "Master" class in it's sub-classes like "Input","Movement",and so on...

Doing so the outer class can call Master.Input, Master.Movement, Master.Other, etc.. and only have access to properties based on the context.

### Example Code

```
//Master class in Master.cs
...
public static class Master{ 
   void Update{
       GetInput(); // Outer class should be able to access some of it's Inner class methods
     }

     public static class Input{
        public Vector2 input;
        internal void GetInput(){ input = ...} // should be visible only to Outer class
     }
}
...
```

---

Now in another file, a class can access Master.Input

```
// Other file: class accessing Master
...
public class InputController{
     Vector2 movInput = Master.Input.input; // okay
     Outer.Inner.GetInput(); // shouldn't be able to do this    
}
...
```

As you can see, the `InputController` can access the `Master` class and `Input` sub-class, but it can also access all the Inner class its `properties` and `methods` freely.
What I want is for the `container class being able to access some of it's nested class methods`, but that any other `outside class only can be able to access it's properties`(In this example Master be able to access "GetInput" but InputController not).

I tried using static classes, namespace and other access modifiers but none of that achieved the result I wanted.

I really hope that what I want can be done in C#, :(

Comment: Don't make it public then. Read up on [C# access modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers).

Comment: Generally if you want completely separate ecosystems, you create different Class Library projects for those separate ecosystems. You can then make it so classes cannot be accessed from outside of the project using the `internal` modifier. However if you want to use nested classes (which I would not recommend), you can make the class `private` and keep the methods `public`. This will also have the effect you want.